# Find the power series for the function

Tags: calculus, power-series

How do I find the power series for f(x)=$\frac{x^3}{x+3}$ ? 
That to in summation notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x^3}{x+3}=\frac13x^3\frac1{1+\frac x3}=\frac13x^3\left(1-\frac x3+\frac {x^2}{3^2}-\frac {x^3}{3^3}+\frac {x^4}{3^4}\cdots\right)$$

Comment: How did you get from the second to the third part? Like how did you come up with the terms and the alternating?

Comment: I used $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots$ and substituted $x\mapsto -\frac x3$.